# Как осуществить последовательное или асинхронное подключение к базам данных?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Перевожу Bash/Perl сценарии на  Python3 столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если хоть один из хостов недоступен, весь цикл просто зависает на первой ошибке и не проходит к следующему  `remote-db-server`

```
Error could not translate host name "remote-db-host-01" to address: Name or service not known

No access to DB app on host remote-db-host-01
```

remote-db-host-0[1-5] приведены в качестве примера, реальные хосты пингуются и все в порядке если напрямую подключится через `psql`

**Вопрос**

Как "сгладить" зависание и перевести каждое подключение в фоновый процесс (если это вообще возможно в цикле Python)

на Bash все проходит без зависаний т.к. ошибки подключения просто игнорируются

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# File : db_sync.py

import psycopg2


remote_db_servers = [
    { "name": "remote-db-server-01", "dbname": "app", "dbhost": "host-01", "dbuser": "username", "dbpass": "password" },
    { "name": "remote-db-server-02", "dbname": "app", "dbhost": "host-02", "dbuser": "username", "dbpass": "password" },
    { "name": "remote-db-server-03", "dbname": "app", "dbhost": "host-03", "dbuser": "username", "dbpass": "password" },
    { "name": "remote-db-server-04", "dbname": "app", "dbhost": "host-04", "dbuser": "username", "dbpass": "password" },
    { "name": "remote-db-server-05", "dbname": "app", "dbhost": "host-05", "dbuser": "username", "dbpass": "password" },
]

query = """
SELECT
    *
FROM
    parameters
"""

for db_server in remote_db_servers:
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' host='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(
            db_server['dbname'],
            db_server['dbhost'],
            db_server['dbuser'],
            db_server['dbpass'],
        ))
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        raws = cur.fetchall()
        for raw in raws:
            print(raw)

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        print(f'Error {e}')
        print("No access to DB {} on host {}".format(customer['dbname'], customer['dbhost']))
        con = None
        pass

    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```

и на Bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File : db_sync.bash

remote_db_servers=(...)

query = "SELECT * FROM parameters;"

for db_server in remote_db_servers[@]
do
    PGPASSWORD=$db_server[dbpass]
    psql -u $db_server[dbuser] \
         -H $db_server[dbhost] \
         -d $db_server[dbname] \
         -c $query &
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Для `asyncpg` как-то так

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg

async def connect_and_get(connstr):
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(connstr)
    values = await conn.fetch(query)
    await conn.close()
    return values



async def main():

    servers = [connect_and_get("dbname='{}' host='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(
            db_server['dbname'],
            db_server['dbhost'],
            db_server['dbuser'],
            db_server['dbpass'],
        )) for db_server in remote_db_servers]

    results = await asyncio.gather(*servers) # Запускает асинхнонные функции конкурентно

    for result in results:
        for row in result:
            print(row)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Асинхронность в 2х словах: `await` продолжает код по мере готовности результата.

Для multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool = Pool(len(remote_db_servers))

def connect_and_get(db_server):
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' host='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(
            db_server['dbname'],
            db_server['dbhost'],
            db_server['dbuser'],
            db_server['dbpass'],
        ))
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        raws = cur.fetchall()
        return raws

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        print(f'Error {e}')
        print("No access to DB {} on host {}".format(customer['dbname'], customer['dbhost']))
        con = None
        pass

    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()


    for raws in pool.imap_unordered(connect_and_get, remote_db_servers):
        for raw in raws:
            print(raw)
```

Comment: Да только начал изучать новые для себя функции ASGI. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: не фурычит `... for row in result:
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future`

Comment: @Hellseher писал на память, может что и забыл ущё) await перед gather